# Question about compact subset of $l^p(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Q) Suppose $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in l^p(\mathbb{N}), 1\leq p<\infty$. Let

$$S=\{(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}: |y_n|\leq |x_n|, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

Prove that $S$ is a compact subset of $l^p(\mathbb{N})$.

At a higher level, I think I need to show that for some sequence in $S$, the $l^p$ distance between the sequence and its limit converges to $0$ but not sure how to approach the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(y_n^{(j)})$ be a sequence in $S$. Note that for each $n$ the sequence $(y_n^{(j)}:j\geq 1) $ is bounded and hence it has a convergent subsequence. By a diagonal procedure we can extract  a subsequence $j_k$ such that $y_n=\lim_{k \to \infty} y_n^{(j_k)}$ exists for every $n$. We now claim that $(y_n^{(j)}) \to (y_n)$ in $l^{p}$. For this  note that given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N} ^{\infty} |y_n^{(j_k)}|^{p} \leq \sum_{n=N} ^{\infty} |x_n|^{p} <\epsilon$. This also implies (by Fatou's Lemma, for example) that $\sum |y_n|^{p} <\infty$.   Can you now show that $\sum |y_n^{j_k} -y_n|^{p} \to 0$?

Comment: I think $\sum |y_n^{j_k}-y_n|^p\to 0$ follows from dominated convergence theorem for counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ but I don't understand the sequence $(y_n^{(j)})$ itself, may I know what we mean by the running index of this sequence being $j$?

Comment: @Garfield $S$ is a space of sequences. To prove that is compact you prove that every sequence in it has a convergent subsequence. A sequence in $S$ is of the type $(y_n^{(1)}), (y_n^{(2)}), ....$

Comment: @Garfield Using DCT is fine but I gave a direct proof not involing measure theory.

Comment: $\sum_n|y_n^{j_k}-y|^p \leq \sum_n |y_n^{j_k}|^p+|y_n|^p$